# Check if MySQLReader Finished Running/Finding Record VB.Net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I want to check if the `MySQLReader` is finished finding my Record.

So far this code helps me finding the record.

```
if reader.HasRows then
   while reader.Read()
   //codes
   end while
else
//else condition codes
end if
```

I really want to know if the `Reader` finished running. Something like `reader.Finished()//**but there's no such thing like this code**`. Can someone help on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reader.Read()` will return false when the `Reader` is finished reading. This will result in your `while` loop terminating. You can do something like this:

```
if reader.HasRows then
   while reader.Read()
       ''codes
   end while
   ''Do whatever it is you wanted to do when the reader is finished.
else
    ''else condition codes
end if
```